# How to pass List model to controller from view http post

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a `CategoryModel` that contains a list item for the `ItemModel` as well as some other strings etc.

I'm trying to pass the list from the view to the controller. The model on the view is the `ABCModel` which contains a list of 'Categories' of type `CategoryModel`. On the view I'm only looking to post the 'active' Category back to be saved.

When I do this the active category is passed with details added from the form but the list of items is null.

#### .cs Models

```cs
    namespace Company.Models
    {
        public class ABCModel
        {
            public IList<CategoryModel> Categories;
            public SummaryModel Summary;
        }
    }
    
    namespace Company.Models
    {
    public class CategoryModel
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public string Frequency { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public List<ItemModel> Items;
    }
    )
    
    namespace Company.Models
    {
    public class ItemModel
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Explanation { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }
        public string Frequency { get; set; }
        public bool Flag { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
    }
    }
```

#### Controller

```cs
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveItems([FromForm] CategoryModel activeCategoryModel, [FromForm] List<ItemModel> items, [FromQuery] string activecategory, [FromQuery] string nextcategory)
        {
        ...
        }
```

#### View

```cs
    @model ABCModel

    @{ CategoryModel nextCategory = null; }
    @{ CategoryModel activeCategoryModel = null; }
    
    @if (Model.Categories.Any())
    {
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count; i++)
        {
            Company.Models.CategoryModel category = Model.Categories[i];
    
            @if (category.Active)
            {
                activeCategoryModel = category;
                if ((i + 1 < Model.Categories.Count) && (Model.Categories[i + 1] != null))
                {
                    nextCategory = Model.Categories[i + 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    <form id="ABC-form" class="needs-validation" novalidate="" asp-action="SaveItems" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    
            @if (activeCategoryModel != null)
            {
                <input asp-for="@activeCategoryModel.Label" type="hidden" />
                <input asp-for="@activeCategoryModel.Active" type="hidden" />
                <input asp-for="@activeCategoryModel.Amount" type="hidden" />
                <input asp-for="@activeCategoryModel.Frequency" type="hidden" />
                <input asp-for="@activeCategoryModel.Type" type="hidden" />

                @if (activeCategoryModel.Items.Any())
                {    
                    @for (var i = 0; i < activeCategoryModel.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => activeCategoryModel.Items[i].Label)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => activeCategoryModel.Items[i].Explanation)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => items[i].Amount, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    }
                }
            }
        <button id="continue" type="submit" asp-action="SaveItems" asp-route-activecategory="@activeCategoryModel.Label" asp-route-nextcategory="@(nextCategory != null ? nextCategory?.Label : null)">Continue</button>
    </form>
```

I had been including `IFormCollection` as a parameter within the SaveItems on the controller and this showed that the items are being passed in the format I was thinking would work but the model only shows the values entered and the list of items is null.

[image: IFormCollection on hover in debug on controller]

[image: activeCategoryModel on hover in debug on controller - items = null]

How can I populate the list of items on the active category model from the view?

Comment: Did your  `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => activeCategoryModel.Items[i].Amount, new { @class = "form-control" })` instead of  `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => items[i].Amount, new { @class = "form-control" })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Items` in `CategoryModel` should be a property not a filed,so your `CategoryModel` should be like below:

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Exactly right, this fixed it - thank you! I was just missing the { get; set; }.